# Can you write and put Custom Apps on your IPhone without joining the IPhone Developer Program?

Tags: iphone

If I want to write some custom IPhone Apps, but not necessarily distribute them through the App Store, is this possible, without joining the IPhone Developer Program?

Lets say I just want to write some little Utility App for myself and put it in my Iphone/Touch, is this possible without joining one of the developer programs?

Answer (score 8):

Not unless you jailbreak your device. You have to pay the $99 to be able to install software on the iPhone. Otherwise you can only test in the iPhone Simulator.

Comment: Thanks.  Talk about nickel and dimming somebody...I don't want to Jailbreak my IPhone, but maybe can Jailbreak my Touch.

Comment: What you want to do is something pretty rare since like .0001% of people want to build apps for themselves and nobody else. I think you're doing the nickel and diming.

Comment: ...and keep in mind that you actually get some value out of those 99 bucks. You will get a couple of case-questions included, you will get invitations to free but registered devs only developer conferences (e.g. TechTalk). Its worth every dime!