# Writing apps for the iPad

Tags: ios, ipad

I would like to know if one can write apps on the iPad without having a developer account.
I'm well aware that you need a developer account to sell apps on the app store; but if you write an app can you use it on your own iPad?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you write and put Custom Apps on your IPhone without joining the IPhone Developer Program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755684/can-you-write-and-put-custom-apps-on-your-iphone-without-joining-the-iphone-devel)

Comment: Try looking at the TOS, API references or other apple development references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly write applications and use the emulator, but you won't be able to deploy the application to your iPad without a developer account.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can run it on the Simulator.

You can practice writing apps without being able to try on a real iPad/iPhone/iPod for free.