# Developing iphone apps without being a apple developer

Tags: ios

I just want to know whether it is possible to not be an apple developer(i.e.  the one in which you pay $99 a year) and yet make apps only for your iPhone. I mean to tell that I want to develop apps but not release them in the appstore. Rather I just want to use it in my iPhone. If its possible can you tell me how do I transfer it to my iPhone?

Comment: Are you using Mac or Windows?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you write and put Custom Apps on your IPhone without joining the IPhone Developer Program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755684/can-you-write-and-put-custom-apps-on-your-iphone-without-joining-the-iphone-deve)

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible. You can develop iPhone app using Xcode and can test it in the simulator but even if you need to test your app on iPhone, You will need the provision profile that is available through your apple developer id and for the same you need to pay $99.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible with a jailbroken device, to achieve what you want. Other than that, just check @Sarah answer.