# Xcode 4.3.2 Apps testing

Tags: ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Test app on iPhone without paying $99 to Apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024704/test-app-on-iphone-without-paying-99-to-apple)

Yesterday I installed Xcode 4.3.2 and I want to test my app on my iPod touch ;)
What should I do to test my app on my iPod for free? ( I can't pay 99$ )
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Numerous duplicates, e.g.: [Test app on iPhone without paying $99 to Apple](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024704/test-app-on-iphone-without-paying-99-to-apple); [Developing iphone apps without being a apple developer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666011/developing-iphone-apps-without-being-a-apple-developer); [Test iOS app on device without apple developer program or jailbreak](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak).

Answer (score 0):

Either you pay the 99$ and get a certificate to install it on your iPod under the sandbox environment for development testing. OR you jailbreak your iPod and follow [the steps here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-a-real-iphone-device)